# PHP - String Variable gets reset outside while loop

Tags: php, string, loops, while-loop, str-replace

maybe this is just a silly question but I'm kinda got stuck on this :(

I want to make multiple changes to a string in a while. But it gets reset if it starts the loop again.

Here is my code (simplified for better understanding):

```
    $string = '<a href="1"></a>_<a href="2"></a>_<a href="3"></a>';
    $offset = 0;
    $i = 1;
    while($i<=3){ 

        $start = strpos($string, '<a href="', $offset);

        $end = strpos($string, '</a>', $offset)+4;

        $sub_string = substr($string,$start,($end-$start));

        $new_string = str_replace($sub_string,'<a data-filter=""></a>',$string);
        echo $i.".: ".htmlentities($new_string)."<br>";

        $offset = $end;      

        $i++;            
    }
```

The echo in the loop puts out the following:

```
1.: <a data-filter=""></a>_<a href="2"></a>_<a href="3"></a>
2.: <a href="1"></a>_<a data-filter=""></a>_<a href="3"></a>
3.: <a href="1"></a>_<a href="2"></a>_<a data-filter=""></a>
```

My problem is that I want the string not to  be reseted ( I think this happens with the string declared outside of the while loop? )

The end result should be:

```
<a data-filter=""></a><a data-filter=""></a><a data-filter=""></a>
```

If I echo the string after the while loop only the changes of the last loop take effect. So I want the string be replaced step by step.

Thank you in advance for your time and answers :)

Comment: You're not actually changing $string, but $new_string; and overwriting the previous changes to $new_string with each successive iteration

Answer (score 0):

your $string variable is not used (not set) within the loop, what you are setting and echoing is $new_string. Depending on your expected output you may want to use something like:

```
$string = $new_string or
$string .= $new_string or
$string[] = $new_string (for this you would have to declare your $string as array).
```

Anyhow, you are not assigning any progress made within the loop to your string variable and that is your issue.

Comment: Hi Auris! That makes sense ;) The str_replace changes the $string variable. But after the whole loop ends only the last change takes effect :P Thats my problem.